# android shortcut, access launcher db

Tags: android, database, sqlite, launcher

I want to get data from launcher db.

```
final String AUTHORITY = "com.android.launcher2.settings";  
final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + 
                        AUTHORITY + "/favorites?notify=true");

Cursor c = contentResolver.query(uri, columns, null, null,
            null);
```

and

```
<uses-permission 
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission 
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
<uses-permission 
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission 
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

but it's said that in logcat:

```
Failed to find provider info for com.android.launcher2.settings
```

Comment: check this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/android/thread?tid=74f6668ec87004b5&hl=en

Answer (score 8):

The launcher is an Application under the Handset Manufacturer responsibility.
The Authority is then not always `"com.android.launcher2.settings"`.
The Handset Manufacturer may rewrite its own.
It can be `"com.android.twlauncher"` or anything else depending on the Java package.

You need to retrieve the right authority by searching for a provider that declares the read/write permissions `"com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"` or `"com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"`.

This is a sample code to do that:

```
static String getAuthorityFromPermission(Context context, String permission){
    if (permission == null) return null;
    List<PackageInfo> packs = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
    if (packs != null) {
        for (PackageInfo pack : packs) { 
            ProviderInfo[] providers = pack.providers; 
            if (providers != null) { 
                for (ProviderInfo provider : providers) { 
                    if (permission.equals(provider.readPermission)) return provider.authority;
                    if (permission.equals(provider.writePermission)) return provider.authority;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Generally, the `ContentProvider` and DB structure is kept, and you can use the same queries.

Answer (score 0):

For my Nexus 5 device different permissions required

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Authority string is `com.google.android.launcher.settings`